# 400 bad request while connecting to sharepoint site using Azure Function app

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, azure-functions

I am new to Azure Functions. I am creating a function to call a SharePoint site but stuck at execute query.

Here is my code -

```
var password = "Somepassword";
var username = "Some login name";
var Url = "Site URL";

using (var context = new ClientContext(Url))
{                 
    var securepass = new SecureString();
    foreach (char c in password)
    {
        securepass.AppendChar(c);
    }
    log.LogInformation("C# HTTP");
    SharePointOnlineCredentials credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, securepass);
    context.Credentials = credentials;
    Web web = context.Web;
    context.Load(web);
    log.LogInformation("web object load");
    context.ExecuteQuery();
```

At execute query I am getting an exception -

> [Information] The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. 
>   [Information] at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SPWebRequestExecutor.Execute()    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.GetFormDigestInfoPrivate()
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.EnsureFormDigest()    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()    at
>   Submission#0.d__1.MoveNext() in
>   D:\home\site\wwwroot\HttpTrigger3\run.csx:line 61  [Information]
>   Executed 'Functions.HttpTrigger3' (Succeeded, Id=Some Id)

I don't understand what's wrong.
Could anyone please help? Thanks!

Comment: you need to use Azure functions v1. Looks like you are using v2, just recreate it using v1 and it should work

Comment: How to change that?

Comment: you need to recreate it again as i mentioned in comments.

Comment: One more thing, do I have to use execute query only once?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create App ID and App Secret ID from SharePoint and connect via that since you are connecting from Azure Functions app.

I did this with PnP PowerShell, you can check how to do the same for CSOM.

PowerShell solution:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -AppId <app-id> -AppSecret <app-secret-id>
```

Comment: I was using different version of function app. Changed the version and it worked.

Comment: @DixitSoni you can post it and accept it as an answer for future reference.